# subprocess - FileNotFoundError when shell=False

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

I'm making a GUI that can execute on the command prompt using subprocess and tkinter.

```
    def test_subprocess(self):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "Hello"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=False)
        response = proc.communicate()[0]
        self.log.insert("end", response)
```

If I set `shell=False`, I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I already have the arguments separated into a sequence.

Answer (score 4):

That is because `echo` is a built-in command in Windows, not an executable. You *have* to enable `shell=True` to make it work.

(or add the shell prefix, such as `bash -c` or `cmd /c` depending on your OS)

ex for you on windows: that works:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/c", "echo", "Hello"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=False)
```

But I suppose this is only an exercise, since running `echo` from `Popen` is overkill for `print` :)

Note: in Linux/UNIX it is built-in too but as cdarke stated, there's a fallback executable in `/bin` on some versions, so that would work.

Comment: Just to add, many UNIX systems have `/bin/echo` as well as the shell builtin, so you probably would only get this particular issue on Windows.

Comment: @cdarke: nice. The user is clearly using windows, the error message is recognizable as the worst ever, not even telling which file it cannot find :)

Comment: Don't you hate it when the filename is not reported?  It damn well *knows* which file it can't find, but can't be bothered to tell us.  You can't even run `strace` to find out.

Comment: Frustrating indeed. I use to protect the `Popen` call with a try/catch block on `WindowsError/FileNotFoundError` and print the full command when exception is trapped.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution than using `bash -c` or `cmd -c` :

starting from python 3.3 you can invoke `shutil.which`

More at https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html :

```
import shutil

proc = subprocess.Popen(
  [shutil.which("echo"), "Hello"], 
  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
  universal_newlines=True, 
  shell=False
)
```